# merging 2 dataframes with converting key to str

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes

df_features which has index called "filename" and type is string

```
df_features
Out[105]: 
code      10012005  10029008  10197000  ...  9735005  9905009  9911007
filename                                ...                           
1              0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
10             0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
100            0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
10000          0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
10001          0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
           ...       ...       ...  ...      ...      ...      ...
9995           0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
9996           0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
9997           0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
9998           0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0
9999           0.0       0.0       0.0  ...      0.0      0.0      0.0

[52713 rows x 4286 columns]
```

another dataframe is df_results which has a column called "filename" but type is numeric

```
df_results
Out[106]: 
      filename                                                                                      result
0          1.0                                     [NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, 280]
1          2.0  [NON, NON, NON, 288, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, 285, 285, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON]
2          3.0       [NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, 285, NON]
3          4.0                                                         [NON, NON, 287, NON, NON, 285, NON]
4          5.0                                                                   [NON, NON, NON, NON, NON]
       ...                                                                                         ...
52708  58593.0                                               [NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, 285]
52709  58674.0                                                         [NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON]
52710  58788.0                                                              [NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON]
52711  59173.0                                               [NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON]
52712  59606.0                           [NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, NON, 285, NON]

[52713 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to merge both dataframes into one on "filename"

so I did this

```
df_results['filename'] = df_results['filename'].astype(str)

df = pd.merge(df_features, df_results, on = 'filename')
```

but when I get df it has not records

so I think the merge was wrong due to the conversion of the filename in df_results to string

my guess is filename became string but with the decimal .0

so the merge is trying to match "1234" with "1234.0" as strings and they do not match

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is convert values to `integer`s before `string`s:

```
df_results['filename'] = df_results['filename'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

If possible missing values use [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df_results['filename'] = df_results['filename'].astype('Int64').astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting to `int` then `str`

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'filename':[1.2,2.3,4.5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.head(5)
```

```
    filename
0   1.2
1   2.3
2   4.5
```

`df["filename"] = df["filename"].fillna(0.0).astype(int).astype(str)`

```
filename
0   1
1   2
2   4
```